# PyOpenCL fails to build program on MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencl, pyopencl, macos-mojave

So I'm trying to run a program using `silx.image.sift`, which uses `pyopencl`. While running the software, I ran into a problem building the openCL program and I've isolated the program to the following code which reproduces the error:

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
from pyopencl.clrandom import rand as clrand


context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)
clrand(queue, (50,), np.float32)
```

Since this code is as basic as it gets, I'm guessing it's a bug with the (regretfully) recently installed macOS Mojave. Here is the error I consistently get whenever I run code that uses `pyopencl`:

> ```
>  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopencl/clrandom.py",
>   line 642, in _fill
>     self.get_gen_kernel(ary.dtype, distribution)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytools/__init__.py",
>    line 598, in wrapper
>     result = function(obj, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopencl/clrandom.py",
>   line 623, in get_gen_kernel
>     prg = cl.Program(self.context, src).build()
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py",
>    line 510, in build
>     options_bytes=options_bytes, source=self._source)
>   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py",
>    line 554, in _build_and_catch_errors
>     raise err
> pyopencl._cl.RuntimeError: clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE - clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE -
>    clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
>
> Build on <pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz' on 'Apple' at 0xffffffff>:
> ```

Not sure whether this is a pyopencl issue or a general opencl problem. I understand that OpenCL is deprecated in macOS mojave, but that shouldn't mean that it won't work at all right?

Comment: Your code works for me an on iMac with MacOS Mojave after installing python3 (3.7.0) with `brew install python` and pyopencl with `pip3 install numpy pybind11 pyopencl`.

Comment: For what it's worth, on 10.12.6 and  POCL 2018.1.1, I get some warnings, e.g., <program source>:17:19: warning: no previous prototype for function 'gen_bits'
            uint4 gen_bits(key_t *key, ctr_t *ctr).
<program source>:66:32: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned long' and 'long'
                while (idx + 4 < out_size). 

Perhaps your problem is related?

Answer (score 2):

According to the developer of PyOpenCL, it's a known problem on Mac OS 10.14. Earlier versions are apparently not affected.

The solution is to use the command in terminal, before running python or jupyter notebook:

```
export PYOPENCL_NO_CACHE=1
```